# Set "installer" package value as returned in getInstallerPackageName()

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have an Android app that uses a WebView to enable users to install applications. Historically, applications installed from Android Market will have the installer value set to "com.google.android.feedback". With Google Play, this value is now "com.android.vending".

This value can be obtained by:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
String installer = pm.getInstallerPackageName(pname);
```

The apps installed by my WebView have an installer value set to null. How can I set my own installer value, such as `com.mydomain.store`?

Comment: The interesting part of the question is missing? Why would you want this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using [`setInstallerPackageName`](http://goo.gl/XJODR).

But you would have to set the installer package name after the package is installed, and the installer package name would have to be empty/null.

Comment: Thanks Jakar, it turned out this functions is available for API Level 11+, and I'm using API Level 7. That's why I couldn't find it. I also found out that the installer app should be signed with the same key as the installed apps.

Answer (score 17):

While this doesn't strictly answer the question to do this programmatically, it's also possible to set the vendor package through adb without needing it to be signed with the same key.

[There's a complete explanation here](http://pixplicity.com/setting-install-vendor-debug-app/), but it boils down to:

> The following adb trick sets the install vendor of a debug app:
>
> ```
> adb push app.apk /data/local/tmp/app.apk
> adb shell pm install -i "com.android.vending" -r /data/local/tmp/app.apk
> adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/app.apk
> ```
>
> To confirm that this has worked, list the packages using the Package
> Manager:
>
> ```
> adb shell pm list packages -i [packagename]
> ```
>
> If all has gone well, you should see this output:
>
> ```
> package:[packagename]  installer=com.android.vending
> ```