# how to use distinguish the app installed was from me or not

Tags: android

I have an appstore that I want to do the same as google play store and amazon store which have unique values when calling `getInstallerPackageName()`. like apps that were installed from amazon would return `com.amazon.venezia` and apps installed from google play would return `com.android.vending`.

is it possible I can do the same? so when calling `getInstallerPackageName()` for the apps that were downloaded and installed from my appstore would return for example `com.myapp.vending`?

also, i know calling `getInstallerPackageName()` would return null if the app is sideloaded, but there might be cases where A app can be downloaded and installed from another 3rd party source and not from my app. both ways of installing this A app would return null when calling `getInstallerPackageName()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set "installer" package value to be returned in getInstallerPackageName()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146820/set-installer-package-value-to-be-returned-in-getinstallerpackagename)

Answer (score 2):

To set the installer package name, you first need to install the app using an Intent, as it appears you have figured out. After the installation is successful, you can call `setInstallerPackageName()` with appropriate parameters.

Sources:

[Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

[PackageManager.setInstallerPackageName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I'm doing the install prompt by throwing an intent like the link you provided. will that throw the package name i have in my manifest when calling `getInstallerPackageName()`?

Comment: @user1865027 I'm not entirely certain. I suggest testing it yourself. You could make a dummy app to install with your installer app.

Comment: no it doesnt work. i cant find a way to set InstallerPackageName. packageManager has the method but makes no sense to set it after the installation.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))? You can call `setInstallerPackageName()` in the installer app.

Comment: yea, but the thing is i dont know how/where to call `setInstallerPackageName(). im basically throwing an intent with path to the apk like the link you provided. i can only set it after installation completes

Comment: i cant set InstallerPackageName in an intent

Comment: In your installer app: 1. Install an app. 2. Call `setInstallerPackageName()` with the desired parameters.

Comment: yes, that post tells you to pass the intent to the system and let android installer to handle the installation. my app only downloads apk then fire up intent

Comment: @user1865027 I think that using an Intent to allow the Android system to install the app is exactly the way to go.

Comment: then there's no way to set installerPackageName. its gonna just be an intent and no `PackageManager`

Comment: @user1865027 Hopefully my edited answer is more clear. I have just tried to add a little more detail to my previous comment. You certainly can set the installer package name by getting the `PackageManager` and calling `setInstallerPackageName()`.

Comment: thanks for the edited answer. but like you said, i can only set installerPackageName **after** the app is installed. there's no additional information passed in the `BroadcastReceiver` to distinguish whether the app was installed from the intent passed by my app or any other apps.

Comment: my point here is that i have something else i want to do after installation, but it wouldnt make sense to call my method if the new app is installed by any other app